# C# - C# Server works as Console Application. Does not work as Web Application

Tags: c#, stream, telnet, writer

I have the following code for a server:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class TCPListener
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            TcpListener listener = null;
            TcpClient client = null;
            NetworkStream stream = null;
            BinaryWriter writer = null;

            try
            {
                listener = new TcpListener(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 1 }), 5000);
                listener.Start();

                while (true)
                {
                    using (client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
                    {
                        using (stream = client.GetStream())
                        {    
                            writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
                            writer.Write("The message was received!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                //Catch socket exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I put this code in a console application and use telnet, I receive `"The message was received"` message on the command prompt.  Now, I copied and pasted this code (changing the namespace) into a web application as a class.  The web application solution was deployed on `port 5000`.  Apart from the server, it also contains a number of pages which the user can browse.

Unfortunately, if I go to telnet and type `"telnet 127.0.0.1 5000"`, a connection is achieved, however I don't receive anything.  What do you think is the problem?  How can I solve it?

Comment: Well in the console app you have a `Main` method which runs this code - what have you got firing it in the web application?

Comment: I put it in a main block as well.  Baiscally, I just copied it as it is, just changed the namespace

Comment: Depending on the framework you will need to use a POST handler or something like that. In any case, exactly this code in a web application don't seem to be appropriate. A web application already defines a communication channel.

Comment: @Matthew: Well that's not going to work. The `Main` method is only invoked automatically when you invoke the executable...

Comment: I see.  How do you think that I should go about the problem?  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `TCPListener tcpListener = new TCPListener();` `tcpListener.Main();`

Comment: @jimtollan Where should I put this code please?

Comment: mathew, in your controller action (or the code behind)

Comment: Thanks.  Do you mean in the page load of the home page?

Comment: yup, exactly :) I'll add this as an answer, with credit to js as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathew,

As aluded to by the emeritus mr skeet, you are only catching half the equation. You need to then instantiate the class and call the Main() method.

Here's how you could do that:

```
TCPListener tcpListener = new TCPListener(); 
tcpListener.Main();
```

Try that in your main point of setup in your web based solution (controller action or page load code behind). Also, change the method signature on Main (remove the static).

Also, you seem to be calling your class inside itself:

```
listener = new TcpListener();
```

That is gonna cause big problems... I would suggest a little refactoring and a rethink about how `Main` works. Your 1st major win would be to rename the example class above away from TCPListener, to something else as there appears to be a collision going on there.

**[EDIT]** To save reading the comments below. The final solution that Matthew took was to go back to the console solution and invoke it from the webapp. This way he scored a couple of wins:

- Existing console app had been tested and worked
- Looser coupling of moving parts
- Extensibility to use in other projects
- Ability to implement and move onto other time sensitive elements of project

The takeaway here is, "always examine the options and think beyond a single solution to solve a problem"

Comment: Thanks Jim.  Unfortunately, I am still experiencing the same problem :s  Thanks again.

Comment: I wil try your suggestions :)  Thanks Jim :)

Comment: I made all the necessary refactoring.  The problem still persists though :s

Comment: of course, the other thing here is that the BinaryWriter is not writing to the Http Response. build it up and actually do a save to a textflie first, then start to play with the http response stream. beyond that, i'm only able to comment on the 3 main points that are visible in your question

Comment: Hmm..  I don't think that is the issue.  The application works perfectly when deployed as a console application, so the code in the class is correct.  It is when I am deploying it on web that it is giving me problems.  I think I am not initiating a reference to it in the correct way.

Comment: ok, there is another approach here then (if it's a time sensitive requirement). keep the console app and invoke it from the web app. looser coupling and has extensibility outside the http environment. i've taken this approach on more than a few occassions when i've stepped back and looked at the requirement vs the solution

Comment: I will keep trying for a few more minutes.  If I don't succeed, I will take the approach you described.  Thank you :)

Comment: I decided to take your approach.  Thank you :)

Comment: matthew, remember, you actually WON by taking the pragmatic path :). glad to have been of (moral) assistance. I'll add the final solution you opted for into the answer, to save punters having to read all the comments

Comment: Thanks again Jim :)  I appreciate it immensely :)

Comment: Agreed Jim :)  Thanks again :)